# Typescript + Karma + Fetch Mock

Tags: typescript, fetch, typescript-typings, fetch-mock

Trying to import fetch mock but when karma starts I get:

You need to include some adapter that implements **karma**.start method!

I've tried all of these with no success:

import {fetchMock}  from 'fetch-mock';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';

I have installed the typings from @types/fetch-mock

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
import * as fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.